# pyc file says "source code string cannot contain null bytes"

Tags: python, python-3.x, bytecode

### Context

I wrote this script `1.py` on macOS using `vim` with the encoding `utf-8`

```py
import sys
sys.path += ['./modules']
from _modules._signal import *
```

and then compiled it using

```sh
python3 -m py_compile 1.py
```

The bytecode `__pycache__/1.cpython-39.pyc` can be executed by

```sh
python3 __pycache__/1.cpython-39.pyc
```

with no problem.

---

## Problem

It is known bytecodes are cross-platform. So I sent the `.pyc` to Windows 10.

Here is the directory tree.

```sh
1/ #We are here at first.
└ 2/
└ 3/
└ __pycache__/
　└ 1.cpython-39.pyc
```

When I execute

```sh
python3 __pycache__/1.cpython-39.pyc
```

or

```sh
cd 2/
python3 ../__pycache__/1.cpython-39.pyc
```

it works (with `ImportError`).

However if I execute

```sh
cd 3/
python3 ../__pycache__/1.cpython-39.pyc
```

it unexpectedly fails. Here is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Why? Is this a bug?

I took the same steps on macOS and Arch Linux and there was no problem. Only Windows 10 gives this error.

---

## Environments

- `Python 3.9.4` (for macOS, Linux and Windows 10)
- macOS Big Sur
- Windows10 (tested cmd, powershell and Cygwin)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the difference is between your run 2 and run 3. Did somethng change other than the folder? is there anything in the `2` or `3` folders that might interfere with Python's operations (e.g. a stray `1.py` file)?

Comment: @Blckknght The difference between `2` and `3` is just their names. Since only `.pyc` file is transferred, a stray `1.py` doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your error message. I was briefly excited that I had done so, but I was in fact trying to compile the `.pyc` file a second time with `-m py_compile` in my command line call to the interpreter. I'd double check again that you're actually running what you think you're running, because this issue doesn't make any sense to me.